# Can the verb "end up" be used as a linking verb?

Tags: verbs, linking-verbs

Can the verb "end up" be a linking verb? E.g. "he ended up homeless"

Comment: Yes: the two-word idiom "end up" takes a predicative complement, in this case "homeless". Note that it can be replaced with "became" with no change of meaning.

Comment: I spent about 20 minutes answering your question, providing citations. You shouldn't mark answers as accepted so quickly. Now I feel my effort was wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The sentence "He ended up homeless" is grammatically correct, and "end up" functions as a linking verb. "End up" is not in my mental list of linking verbs, but I'm confident of my claim for two reasons.

First, "homeless" is a subject complement, and that requires a linking verb.

Second, "ended up" can be replaced with "became", and keep the same function and close enough to the same meaning. I'm confident "become" is a linking verb, so "end up" must be one too.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb **end up** can sometimes be a linking verb, and sometimes an action verb.

Here's an explanation and tip for identifying linking verbs:

> A verb is a linking verb if it’s used to describe the subject. Linking
> verbs always have a subject complement afterward.

- Source: [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/linking-verbs/)

Regarding the phrasal verb **end up**, [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/end-up) has some good illustrations to help make this clear.

> 1. If someone or something **ends up** somewhere, they eventually
>    arrive there, usually by accident: *She fled with her children, moving
>    from neighbor to neighbor and **ending up** in a friend's basement.*

In this case, *ending up* is an **action**, and *a friend's basement* describes the result of the action.

> 2. If you end up doing something or end up in a particular state, you
>    do that thing or get into that state even though you did not
>    originally intend to: *Every time they went dancing they **ended up**
>    in a bad mood.*

In this case, *ending up* is a **linking** verb because *a bad mood* is describing the subject *they*.